# Returning two values at the same time in a function

Tags: c, function, return-value, multiple-return-values

How can I return two integer type values at the same time in one function in the C programming language or should I write two different functions?

Comment: This kind of answer can be easily found using google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `struct` in which you have two integers and return this `struct` as the result of your function.

In a language such C, you can store your data in `struct` like this :

```
struct foo {
 int x;
 int y;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean use array by the term "struct".

Comment: English, please. @eestudent

Comment: No, he meant struct.

Answer (score 3):

Two different functions or pass by reference parameters.

e.g.

```
void someFunc(int* outParam1, int* outParam2)
{
    if (outParam1 != NULL) {
        *outParam1 = 42;
    }
    if (outParam2 != NULL) {
        *outParam2= 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean _pass by pointer_ ?

Comment: Implementation in C is "pass by pointer", but the name of the programming technique is more generally called "pass by reference".

Answer (score 3):

If return them is not mandatory and you can accept to use pointers, it follows a possible approach:

```
void your_function(/* some other parameters */ int *ret1, int *ret2) {
    int first_value, second_value;
    // do whatever you want there
    *ret1 = first_value; // first_value is the first value you want to return, quite obvious
    *ret2 = second_value; // still obvious
}
```

Then, you can invoke it as follows:

```
// somewhere
int r1, r2;
your_function(/* other parameters */ &r1, &r2);
// here you can use "returned" values r1, r2
```

Answer (score 1):

In C a function can return only one value.
You can pass a variable by address to the function and modify it with the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int returnTwoInt(int *var2)
{
    *var2 = 2;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int var2 = 0;
    int var1 = returnTwoInt(&var2);

    printf("%d %d\n", var1, var2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of ways -

Use `struct` and return `struct variable` .

Or

Make the function to handle the arguments with pointers.
Ex-

```
void f1(int *x, int *y){

*x  = 1;
*y  = 2;

 }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int x,y;
f1(&x, &y);
printf("%d %d",x,y);
return 0;
 }
```